# The new post timeline view changes alignment when line items are expanded

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, firefox, timeline

With the [recent update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247647/253521) of the post timeline page coming out today, I've noticed a bug in Firefox.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to a question's timeline page. For example: [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/168686/timeline).
2. Click on the arrow near any "edited" lines to expand the edited preview of the post.

You'll notice that the timeline shifts to right-alignment when the post preview is displayed, instead of staying left-aligned. This is true for any type of edit (post, tags, etc.).

I'm assuming this is a bug and that the timeline should not be jumping around the page like this in Firefox, since it doesn't do this in Chrome. Visual examples:

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Comment: [Huh?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ceOw0.png)

Comment: @nicael Updated. I'm in Firefox 43.

Comment: [Cannot reporduce](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wIYjY.jpg) Win7 pro x64 Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 m

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We all *love* Firefox's rendering engine quirks. Especially when they break jQuery's `toggle()`.

Fixed by using `toggleClass("dno")`, but... [seriously Firefox](https://i.imgur.com/g5JJ6Mo.gif).

Fix is going out in `rev 2015.12.23.4024` (meta) and `rev 2015.12.23.3129` (main).

(kudos to [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3522761/7028) for the correct solution)

Answer (score 7):

Pinpointed. The parent row is being set to `display: block` via an inline style, so it isn't being rendered as part of a table anymore and `colspan` gets completely ignored on the cell. Things just kinda break, badly, when you try to put a block directly inside a table like that. Removing that style seems to fix things.

Chrome seems to simply remove that style declaration and ignores it on its own (leaves an empty style attribute), which is why it gets rendered correctly there. But you can break it manually (exact same rendering as Firefox) by reintroducing the `display: block` as an inline style.

Will poke someone to fix.